# Ms Dynamics Nav Multi Language with PHP

Tags: php, microsoft-dynamics, dynamics-nav, microsoft-dynamics-nav, microsoft-dynamics-webapi

```
public function productDetails($product_code){
    $url = 'Page/ProductGroups';
    try {
      $client = $this->initClient($url);
      // $filter = ['Field' => 'Product_Group_Code', 'Criteria' => $product_code];
      $result = $client->ReadMultiple(['filter' => [], 'setSize' => 100]);
      return $result;
    }catch (Exception $e) {
        echo $e->getMessage();
    }
  }
```

This is how I get records from Ms dynamics Nav. All the results are based on the English Language. I need to figure out how we can get records based on other languages like De. Thanks in Advance.

Comment: I think the only way to do it is on Nav side. You need to switch language in settings of web-services’s instance.

Comment: Is there any alternate solution via API. @MakSim

Comment: What exactly are you willing to see in other language? Amounts?

Comment: ...Also note that Product Groups don't have translations/multi-language description values, unlike Items (See table35 - Item Translations).

Comment: @MakSim Each product has specifications,short description,name which are different for the same product with change in language.

for Eg : product name in English : Classic Polo Shirt
                                    in De : Capak Polio
Like wise

Comment: @ian_scho I mentioned product group as just one example my motive is to get the data based on language.

Comment: What ian_scho is trying to explain to you is that item description is special rare case when you do have translations and translations are stored in the separate table. To access it you don’t need to change language. You need to publish page corresponding to table 35 and read it with filter by language.

Comment: See @MakSim we can apply the filter on only those which are listed.

For eg: en - classic
              de - calsso

If the response is like this then we can filter them based on language.

Here i am only receiving response from One language.

Comment: Then you need to create several Nav instances dedicated for each language you want to query. Url will be like “https://whatever.azure.com:7047/NAV_EN/WS/CRONUS” or “https://whatever.azure.com:7047/NAV_DE/WS/CRONUS”. Alternatively you can separate them by port number.

Comment: Ok thanks, bro let me check with the Nav developer regarding the same.

Answer (score 1):

By default, NAV web services are set up to work in en-US culture - that is, English language for multilanguage captions and US format for dates (02/16/18) and decimal amounts (23.37).

There are several ways to influence this behavior:

---

First, there is a block of related parameters in NAV Server configuration - Services Default Company, Services Default Time Zone etc:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd355055(v=nav.90).aspx#General

You need the parameter "Services Language", which allows to select the culture used by NAV web services to process requests.

This configuration is static, but you can create several NAV service endpoints to have different configurations and switch between them.

---

Second, it is possible to setup NAV to process requests of different users using a culture specified in the NAV setup for this user. It is described in more detail in the following blog post: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/nav/2015/03/26/culture-settings-on-nav-web-services/

Using this feature, it is possible either to use different users to get different language/culture, or to change the culture of a current user by separate request to NAV.

Comment: https://inviqa-msnav.northeurope.cloudapp.azure.com:7047/NAV/WS/CRONUS UK Ltd/Page/Item

This is an example of how we call Soap normally.
Can you share a similar example with language parameter?
Thanks in advance.